# i need to separate the string and integer and also to display it in separate columns

Tags: java

Java System.out.printf function allowes you to print formatted output. This problem will test your knowledge on this topic.

Take exactly 3 lines of input. Each line consists of a string and an integer. Suppose this is the sample input:

java 100
cpp 65
python 50

The strings will have at most 10 alphabetic characters and the integers will range between 0 to 999.

## In each line of output there should be two columns. The string should be in the first column and the integer in the second column. This is the output for the input above:

java           100 
cpp            065

## python         050

The first column should be left justified using exactly 15 characters. The integer of the second column should have exactly 3 digits. If the original input has less than 3 digits, you should pad with zeros to the left.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "[Questions asking for homework help must include a **summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem**, and a **description of the difficulty you are having solving it**.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)"

Comment: I had to vote this as unclear. You have not asked a single question.

Comment: It looks like you're posting a homework question. Please show us what you've done. You might find this [meta-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) helpful on what you should try first and how to reword your question.

Answer (score 15):

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner scanner =  new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i=0;i<2;i++){
       String string = scanner.next();
       int num = scanner.nextInt();


       System.out.printf("%-14s %03d %n", string, num);       //note the use of printf
       // %-14s  fifteen characters left-justified o to 14
       // %03d padded with leading zero

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

Use this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            String s1=sc.next();
            int x=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.printf("%-14s %03d %n", s1, x);
            // %-14s left-justified from o to 14 for string
            // %03d padded with leading zero for int
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class Solution {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("================================");
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            String s1=sc.next();
            int x=sc.nextInt();
           System.out.printf("%-15s%03d%n",s1,x);
        }
        System.out.println("================================");

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

public class asd {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "java 100";
    int number;
    String snum = "";
    String text = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        switch (s.charAt(i)) {
        case '0':
            snum += "0";
            break;
        case '1':
            snum += "1";
            break;
        case '2':
            snum += "2";
            break;
        case '3':
            snum += "3";
            break;
        case '4':
            snum += "4";
            break;
        case '5':
            snum += "5";
            break;
        case '6':
            snum += "6";
            break;
        case '7':
            snum += "7";
            break;
        case '8':
            snum += "8";
            break;
        case '9':
            snum += "9";
            break;

        default:
            text += s.charAt(i);
            break;
        }
    }
    number = Integer.parseInt(snum);
    System.out.print(text + " " + number);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class Solution {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("================================");
           for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
   String string = sc.next();
   int num = sc.nextInt();


   System.out.printf("%-14s %03d %n", string, num);



}
     System.out.println("================================");

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("================================");
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
                String s1=sc.next();
                int x=sc.nextInt();
                int j=0;
                if(s1.length()<=10&&j<1000)
                {
                    String StringFormatted = String.format("%-15s",s1);
                    System.out.print(StringFormatted);
                    if(x<100)
                    {
                        String padded = String.format("%03d",x);
                        System.out.print(padded);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.print(x);
                    }
                    //System.out.print(x);
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
            System.out.println("================================");

    }
```